# Play framework: How to apply database evolution to a fake applikation test database

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I´m using the play framework 2.4 together with ebean data models und evolutions. At the moment I'm trying to write the first test for my models using a test mysql database. I want to have a clean test database before I start my tests.

So far I tried this:

```
public class ModelUnitTest {

    public static FakeApplication app;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startApp() {
        // Load test config  with testserver
        Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<String, String>();
        settings.put("db.default.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        settings.put("db.default.url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sopra-ws1516-team10-test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false");
        settings.put("db.default.username", "root");
        settings.put("db.default.password", "root");
        settings.put("play.evolutions.autoApply", "true");
        settings.put("ebean.default", "models.ebean.*");
        app = play.test.Helpers.fakeApplication(settings);

        Evolutions.applyEvolutions(XXXXXX);

        Helpers.start(app);
    }



    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        try {
            User testUser = User.createUser("Max", "Musterman", "01.01.1980", "max.mustermann@gmail.com", "1234");
            assertNotNull(testUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            assertNull(e);
        }
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void stopApp() {
        Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(XXXXXX);
        Helpers.stop(app);
    }

}
```

Without the evolutions it works but the problem is that I can not be sure to have a empty database when I start my tests. My solution would be to apply evolutions before and clean evolutions after my tests. This would give me a clean environment for my tests.

But it is actually not possible to use the `Evolutions` class without having a `Database` object and it seems like there is no way to create a database object using the DB connections my FakeApplication has created.

Does someone has a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unlikeley that I have found a solutions for this but I will inspect my old code.

Answer (score 0):

I got around it by manually invoking the injector:

```
private static Database db;

@BeforeClass
public static void startApp() {
    ...
    app = play.test.Helpers.fakeApplication(settings);

    db = app.injector().instanceOf(Database.class);
    Evolutions.applyEvolutions(db);

    Helpers.start(app);
}

@AfterClass
public static void stopApp() {
    Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(db);
    Helpers.stop(app);
}
```